# ExtJS FormPanel Only Rendered to Panel the First time it is Selected

Tags: extjs

My Form Panels need to be rendered based on a selection in an XML tree structure. However, my form panel for a specific node is only rendered the first time. When I change the selection to something else and return to the original selection, the form panel is not re-rendered.

It was rendering correctly based on the selection before when I had a simple Ext.Template and I did

var temp = Ext.getCmp('details-panel').body;

and then

(Ext.Template's name).overwrite(temp, node.attributes).

When I changed this overwrite line to

(Form Panel's name).render(temp), it only works the first time.

Any idea what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to re-render the whole form panel every time the selection changes? Why not just update the form's fields values?

Answer (score 0):

A component will only render once in ExtJS, after this you need to make use of doLayout() after adding and removing child components.

```
formPanel.doLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand. I basically have

```
    tp.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', function(tree, node){
          var el = Ext.getCmp('temp-panel').body;
          el.update("");
           if(node && node.....){
                myForm.render(el);
           }
```

I want different form panels to show up based on which node I click on. So in the if (node && ...) block I need to render a specific formpanel everytime I switch my selection to this node. Right now it is only happening on the first time. Would calling myForm.doLayout() solve this issue?